# Child of a flex-item not taking parent's height when parent has flex-basis set in a flex container of direction column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Boy that title was a mouthful. Let me explain my confusion:

I have a flex-container and 2 flex items.

```
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="item-1">
        <div class="child-of-item-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-2></div>
</div>


/* CSS */

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.item-1 {
    flex: 0 0 255px;
}

.item-2 {
   /* negligible css */
}

.child-of-item-1 {
    height: 100%; // shouldn't this always receive the height of its parent?
}
```

`item-1` is set with a `flex-basis` of `255px` using the shorthand `flex` property. Since I didn't specify a `flex-direction` on `.container`, it's defaulting to `row`. Simple. Great.

Now at a certain screen width, let's say `992px`, I switch the `flex-direction` to column.

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Here's where my question comes in. Once `<992px`, `.item-1` still has a height of 255px but `.child-of-item-1` loses its height completely. Where have I gone wrong? What am I missing?

It may be important to note that `.child-of-item-1` has no content inside of it, but it does have a `background-image`. I am not seeing the `background-image` because `.child-of-item-1` loses its height, hence my confusion.

I would really appreciate some insight, and thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it only took 2 minutes of posting this before discovering the issue. The parent `.container` had a `min-height`, and therefore would always have a height. This isn't so important when `flex-direction` is set to `column`, but when set to `row`, the flex-container has a height. Removing that `min-height` from the equation, `.item-1`, who has a `flex-basis` of `255px`, would still have no height. BUT, `.item-2` could possibly have a height based on its content. In my case it did. Removing `.item-2` from the equation reveals that `.item-1` never had a height set at all, it was just receiving it from other elements. Once I switched the `flex-direction: column`, the truth came out!

Hope that helps :)